# nokogiri not installing in ruby 2.7.1 centos 7.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, nokogiri

```
Getting below error when installing nokogiri i tried
```

install -y make gcc rpm-build ruby-devel zlib-devel 
gem install nokogiri

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200716-18065-1jmltdp.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.10
with the following patches applied:
        - 0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch
        - 0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch
        - 0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch
        - 0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch
        - 0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.10.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.10... OK
Running patch with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0001-Revert-Do-not-URI-escape-in-server-side-includes.patch... OK
Running patch with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0002-Remove-script-macro-support.patch... OK
Running patch with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0003-Update-entities-to-remove-handling-of-ssi.patch... OK
Running patch with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0004-libxml2.la-is-in-top_builddir.patch... OK
Running patch with /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/patches/libxml2/0005-Fix-infinite-loop-in-xmlStringLenDecodeEntities.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Running 'install' for libxml2 2.9.10... OK
Activating libxml2 2.9.10 (from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libxml2/2.9.10)...
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxslt-1.1.34.

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install
************************************************************************
Extracting libxslt-1.1.34.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxslt/1.1.34... OK
Running 'configure' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'compile' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Running 'install' for libxslt 1.1.34... OK
Activating libxslt 1.1.34 (from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ports/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libxslt/1.1.34)...
checking for -llzma... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri
make "DESTDIR="
compiling html_document.c
compiling html_element_description.c
compiling html_entity_lookup.c
compiling html_sax_parser_context.c
compiling html_sax_push_parser.c
compiling nokogiri.c
compiling xml_attr.c
compiling xml_attribute_decl.c
compiling xml_cdata.c
compiling xml_comment.c
compiling xml_document.c
xml_document.c: In function ‘dealloc’:
xml_document.c:49:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘rb_st_foreach’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   st_foreach(node_hash, dealloc_node_i, (st_data_t)doc);
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/intern.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:2148,
                 from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_document.h:4,
                 from xml_document.c:1:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/st.h:141:5: note: expected ‘int (*)(st_data_t,  st_data_t,  st_data_t)’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)(struct xmlNode *, struct xmlNode *, struct xmlDoc *)’
 int rb_st_foreach(st_table *, st_foreach_callback_func *, st_data_t);
     ^
xml_document.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-cast-function-type" [enabled by default]
compiling xml_document_fragment.c
compiling xml_dtd.c
compiling xml_element_content.c
compiling xml_element_decl.c
compiling xml_encoding_handler.c
compiling xml_entity_decl.c
compiling xml_entity_reference.c
compiling xml_io.c
xml_io.c: In function ‘io_read_callback’:
xml_io.c:20:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   string = rb_rescue(read_check, (VALUE)args, read_failed, 0);
   ^
In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
**/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:7: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE *)’
 VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);**
       ^
*xml_io.c:20:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
   string = rb_rescue(read_check, (VALUE)args, read_failed, 0);
   ^*
In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
                 from ./nokogiri.h:33,
                 from ./xml_io.h:4,
                 from xml_io.c:1:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:7: note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE (*)(void)’
 VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
       ^
```

> xml_io.c: In function ‘io_write_callback’:
> xml_io.c:47:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
> size = rb_rescue(write_check, (VALUE)args, write_failed, 0);
> ^
> In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
> from ./nokogiri.h:33,
> from ./xml_io.h:4,
> from xml_io.c:1:
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:7:
> note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE)’ but argument is of type ‘VALUE
> (*)(VALUE *)’
> VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);
> ^
> xml_io.c:47:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘rb_rescue’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
> size = rb_rescue(write_check, (VALUE)args, write_failed, 0);
> ^
> In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby.h:33:0,
> from ./nokogiri.h:33,
> from ./xml_io.h:4,
> from xml_io.c:1:
> /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/include/ruby-2.7.0/ruby/ruby.h:1987:7:
> note: expected ‘VALUE (*)(VALUE,  VALUE)’ but argument is of type
> ‘VALUE (*)(void)’
> VALUE rb_rescue(VALUE(*)(VALUE),VALUE,VALUE(*)(VALUE,VALUE),VALUE);

```
       ^
***xml_io.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-cast-function-type" [enabled by default]
compiling xml_libxml2_hacks.c
compiling xml_namespace.c
compiling xml_node.c
xml_node.c: In function ‘reparent_node_with’:
xml_node.c:304:7: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘xmlFree’ discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
       xmlFree(reparentee->ns->prefix);
       ^***
xml_node.c:304:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘const xmlChar *’
xml_node.c: At top level:
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-cast-function-type" [enabled by default]
compiling xml_node_set.c
compiling xml_processing_instruction.c
compiling xml_reader.c
compiling xml_relax_ng.c
compiling xml_sax_parser.c
compiling xml_sax_parser_context.c
compiling xml_sax_push_parser.c
compiling xml_schema.c
compiling xml_syntax_error.c
compiling xml_text.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
compiling xslt_stylesheet.c
xslt_stylesheet.c:112:13: warning: ‘swallow_superfluous_xml_errors’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static void swallow_superfluous_xml_errors(void * userdata, xmlErrorPtr error, ...)
             ^
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-tautological-compare" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-self-assign" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-parentheses-equality" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-constant-logical-operand" [enabled by default]
cc1: warning: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-cast-function-type" [enabled by default]
linking shared-object nokogiri/nokogiri.so
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--compress-debug-sections=zlib'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [nokogiri.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Comment: it is not formated but i hope it will give idea

Comment: i think you also need libxml-devel and libxslt-devel or whatever they're called...

Comment: "it is not formated but i hope it will give idea". Then format it. Formatting correctly is an important part of asking a question, and of being a member of the community. Please read these, then edit and improve your question: "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". Remember, when you don't put in the effort to ask a question well, it's less understandable, less likely to get a useful answer, and it forces us to try to fix it.

Comment: @NickM i getting msg  Package libxml2-devel-2.9.1-6.el7.4.x86_64 already installed and latest version and Package libxslt-devel-1.1.28-5.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version. So libxml2 and libxlt latest package is already there.

Comment: Just found nokogiri 1.11.0.rc2 is installing, not sure if this version is stable to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Centos version was 7.6 and all provided solution for nokogiri was not working. Finally i updated centos to 7.8 and it worked. i tried with centos 7.7 version in other server also, it worked on 7.7 also.

Answer (score 8):

as far as my version of centos is old and `/usr/bin/ld` is a part of `binutils`, so my suggestion

```
$ sudo yum update binutils
```

helped me (instead of full OS update)

Answer (score 1):

i encountered exactly same problem.
It seems that the real error is

> /usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '--compress-debug-sections=zlib'

The flag "--compress-debug-sections=zlib" is defined in file /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/nokogiri-1.10.10/ext/nokogiri/Makefile .
This makefile is created by a mkmf.rb, and default value of flags are in this file /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/x86_64-linux/**rbconfig.rb**

> CONFIG["DLDFLAGS"] = "-Wl,--compress-debug-sections=zlib"

After I changed this line to be

> CONFIG["DLDFLAGS"] = ""

gem install nokogiri  works well

But I am not sure about the exactly function of flag "--compress-debug-sections=zlib" and what would happen when i removed it

Answer (score 1):

This error comes because the default linker on `Centos 7.4` does not support that option `--compress-debug-sections=zlib`. `Centos 7.8` seems to fix this issue.

But in case you could not switch to `Centos 7.8`, the option is supported by the gold linker (`ld.gold`).

To enable the use, you could override the linker by doing something like

```
ln -s /bin/ld.gold ~/bin/ld; PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

then run the needed command